# Vue CLI3 - jQuery and Select2 - Compiling Error

Tags: jquery, vue.js, jquery-select2, vue-cli

I have just started with Vue.js and created a project with Vue CLI3. The objective is to eventually migrate my current app to Vue. 
I am experimenting with jQuery and Select2 because this was used in my current app and I would like to know if this approach is correct and why I am still receiving compiling errors even though it seems to work.
Note: I did install the jQuery dependency via the Vue UI.

Here is what I have:

main.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";

/* Custom */
import "./js/jquery.js";
import "./js/select2.js";
import "./css/select2.css";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");

$("#select2-test").select2();
```

Home.vue - View

```
<template>
  <select2_test></select2_test>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import select2_test from "@/components/select2_test.vue";

export default {
  name: "home",
  components: {
    select2_test
  }
};
</script>
```

select2_test.vue - Component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <select id="select2-test" class="form-control" style="width: 50%">
      <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
      <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "select2_test"
};
</script>
```

Added to .eslintrc.js

```
"globals": {
"jQuery": true,
"$": true,
"global": true,
"window": true,
"document": true,
"process": true,
"module": true,
"console": true,
"sessionStorage": true,
"localStorage": true
}
```

Questions:

1. Is this approach correct?
2. Why do I receive a compiling error?:

   Module Warning (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
   error: '$' is not defined (no-undef) at src/main.js:19:1:
   17 | }).$mount("#app");
   18 | 
   19 | $("#select2-test").select2();
   | ^
   20 |

Please help! Thank you guys so much!!!

**UPDATE:**

I moved the $("#select2-test").select2(); to the component and initiate it when mounted. After cleaning up my VSCode setup and restarting, I am not getting any errors anymore. Still, I would like to get an opinion if this is the right approach.:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <select id="select2-test" class="form-control" style="width: 50%">
      <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
      <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "select2_test",
  mounted() {
    $("#select2-test").select2();
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Does jquery.js definitely create the `$` alias?

Comment: @RoyJ I think it does now. I did have to fix my VSCode setup a little bit and restarted the app. I am not getting any errors now. I was also able to move $("#select2-test").select2(); from the main.js to the select2_test.vue component. Updated the original post

Answer (score 0):

In general, use a `ref` to get your element instead of relying on jQuery or getElementById.

```
  <select ref="theSelect" class="form-control" style="width: 50%">
```

```
mounted() {
    $(this.$refs.theSelect).select2();
  }
```

You might also want to bind the select's value to a data member.

```
  <select v-model='theValue' ref="theSelect" class="form-control" style="width: 50%">
```

And then add `theValue` to your data option.  Then you can just get and set the select's value using `this.theValue`.  You can also `watch` it and react to changes.

Finally, any other `Vue` computed properties or directives that depend on `theValue` will recalculate as needed.

Comment: Thanks Steven. I tried your approach using the "ref" but it looks like the select2 is not loaded on the dropdown now. However,  don't get any errors when compiling. The browser debugger shows: this.$refs.select2test.select2 is not a function.Can you help me understand what I am missing? Is there a dependency that I need? I am definitely going to use the 'v-model' value. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have an update? I have tried multiple approaches using ref, none seem to work. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Meisold In mounted, add this: `console.log(this.$refs.theSelect)` and respond with the output.  Is it your HTML element?